# Accuracy of reported measurements

Tags: mean, reporting, precision

I take three measurements: 71, 72 and 74. Each of the three measurements have 2 significant digits. The mean of my three measurements is 72.33 (rounded to 4 significant digits).

Because my measurements have 2 significant digits, should the mean value I report also have 2 significant digits. Therefore should the mean value I report be 72?

Comment: What kinds of measurements are these? If they're counts of discrete objects (as opposed to, say, lengths measured in inches), then you could argue that they actually have infinitely many significant figures.